# SQL Aggragates, and Alias's

Tags: sql

I have a query that needs to return a scalar value if the item is referenced in the table more then once.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    Items
WHERE
    FKID = 2003799
GROUP BY 
    FKID 
HAVING 
    COUNT(*)>1 
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(*)
```

Why can't I assign the aggragate an alias, and reference the alias in in the rest of the query instead of repeating the aggragate function?

Something like:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS CountById
FROM 
    Items
WHERE
    FKID = 2003799
GROUP BY 
    FKID 
HAVING 
    CountById>1 
ORDER BY 
    CountById
```

Edit - Is there an alternative syntax that allows the same idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `SELECT` clause is executed **after** the `HAVING` clause, so when the engine reads the `HAVING` clause, it doesn't know yet what `CountById` means.

Comment: Makes sense, do you know if there is a way to accomplish the same idea though? Having to repeat the aggragate function like this leaves a bad taste in my mouth.

Comment: shouldn't leave a bad taste...it is the proper way to do what you are trying to do!

Comment: In case of a very complex expression that you have to repeat both in HAVING clause and in the SELECT list you can always resort to using derived tables (where they are supported, of course). Give an aggregate expression an alias and turn your (inner) HAVING condition into an outer WHERE one, where you can use that alias.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, the answer is... the SELECT list is interpreted last... Here's basically the order... see http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/how-do-i-use-a-select-list-alias-in-the-where-or-group-by-clause.html.

1. Start in the FROM clause and build a working table from all of the joins, unions, intersections, and whatever other table constructors are there. The  AS  option allows you give a name to this working table which you then have to use for the rest of the containing query.
2. Go to the WHERE clause and remove rows that do not pass criteria; that is, that do not test to TRUE (reject UNKNOWN and FALSE). The WHERE clause is applied to the working in the FROM clause.
3. Go to the optional GROUP BY clause, make groups and reduce each group to a single row, replacing the original working table with the new grouped table. The rows of a grouped table must be group characteristics: (1) a grouping column (2) a statistic about the group (i.e. aggregate functions) (3) a function or (4) an expression made up of the those three items.
4. Go to the optional HAVING clause and apply it against the grouped working table; if there was no GROUP BY clause, treat the entire table as one group.
5. Go to the SELECT clause and construct the expressions in the list. This means that the scalar subqueries, function calls and expressions in the SELECT are done after all the other clauses are done. The AS operator can give a name to expressions in the SELECT list, too. These new names come into existence all at once, but after the WHERE clause has been executed; you cannot use them in the SELECT list or the WHERE cluase for that reason.
6. Nested query expressions follow the usual scoping rules you would expect from a block structured language like C, Pascal, Algol, etc. Namely, the innermost queries can reference columns and tables in the queries in which they are contained.

Answer (score 1):

The reason has to do with the order of processing for a query. `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` are evaluated before the `SELECT` is processed, so your alias is undefined at that time. On the other hand, `ORDER BY` is processed after `SELECT`, so your column alias is valid there.

From [Pinal Dave's Blog](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/), evaluation order is:

1. FROM
2. ON
3. OUTER
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. CUBE | ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP

Answer (score 1):

Usually the `SELECT` list is the last part of the statement to be evaluated (even though it is the first part!) so there is no way to use an alias defined there in other clauses of the statement.